# How can i get all the biggest array instance in a list of different string values in java 8

Tags: java, list, max

For example i have the below list. I want to get only the maximum value of each member.

```java
[customer[0],customer[1],customer[2],device-ip[0],device-ip[1]]
```

My Result will be:

```java
[customer[2],device-ip[1]]
```

so far i have achieved the result with the below code. is there anything simpler than this?

```java
            Collections.sort(keyList);
            String[] keyArray = keyList.toArray(new String[keyList.size()]);
            for (String key : keyArray)
                log.info(key);

            for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
                if (i + 1 == keyArray.length) {
                    resultkeyList.add(keyArray[i]);
                } else {
                    if (!keyArray[i].replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "")
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(keyArray[i + 1].replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", ""))) {
                        resultkeyList.add(keyArray[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please provide code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have attached the working code. but if there is any simpler approach let me know

Comment: If the code works, you should post it in the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stackoverflow doesn't provide feedback or code reviews

Answer (score 0):

you can say something like that :

```
myList.forEach(element -> {

if(element  instanceof customer){

// compare if it is greater than old maksimum value of customer

} else if (element instanceof device-ip){

// compare if it is greater than old maksimum value of device ip
  }

});
```

you can do it in that way.